# Best practice - Builder inside an entity factory

Tags: entity-framework, builder, entities, factories

I was wondering:

1. How legitimate and what the objections would be to place a builder inside an entity factory?
2. Whether these should be called from a manager.

I am not one hundred percent convinced that this would be best practice. However, it seems natural to refactor my application in this way. Is this due to bad design?